# Exclude files and directories from XCode 4 PhoneGap Build

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, build

I know I can deselect "Target Membership" in the Utility Pane in XCode 4 to prevent a file from being included in an XCode build; however, for PhoneGap/Cordova apps, only the root www/ directory actually lists that as an option.  The directories inside www/ can't be untargetted.

The other option I am vaguely familiar with is using `EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES` in the Build Settings, although I'm not exactly sure if that can be used to exclude directories in addition to files.

What would be the best solution to remove (for example), the following directories/files from a build:

```
/www/js/app/
/www/js/vendor/
/www/html/some_page.html
```

Obviously I'd like to leave those files there for development (since I'm just running a build script to cat/minimize them).

Answer (score 3):

In your project root, add a file list this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
# ATTENTION: You must use the following to run as RunScript target in Xcode
# ${PROJECT_DIR}/$PROJECT_NAME/remove_files.sh
# 
# Remove all unwanted files
if ! [ -d $DSTROOT ]; then
        echo "$DSTROOT is not a directory, probably is non-archive build. Exiting.";
        exit 0;
fi
cd $DSTROOT
cat "$PROJECT_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME/exclude_files.txt" | while read file; do find . -name "$file" | xargs -n1 rm -Rf; done
```

Then create the file YourProject/exclude_files.txt and fill it with filenames to remove (may use wildcards):

```
*.svg
README
```

Now add a new RunScript build target and enter

```
"$PROJECT_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME/remove_files.sh"
```

into the box where the script code is usually placed.

Comment: A decent solution but it does not handle folder paths. it is not able to rm files contained in a specific folder, such as patha/pathb/* but it will remove all files inside pathb, as long as that is a unique path within the entire www folder structure (and no desirable files have that file name). thanks for this.

Comment: What is $DSTROOT supposed to map to? I keep getting: '/tmp/MyApp.dst is not a directory, probably is non-archive build. Exiting.'